Google Closure Compiler - Unsupported Class Version
I just upgraded to Windows 11, and am now unable to run the Google Closure compiler. I have the Java 8 JRE installed, but I get an unsupported class version error:
C:\Users\Dick\Documents\tch\code\closure-compiler>java -jar closure-compiler-v20220803.jar --js ..\..\site\js\meter-new.js  --js_output_file  ..\..\site\js\meter-new-compiled.js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

C:\Users\Dick\Documents\tch\code\closure-compiler>java -version
java version "1.8.0_421"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_421-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.421-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

As you can see, I have JRE 1.8.0_421, which I just installed from the Oracle site.
Anyone see why closure compiler won’t run?

class version 55.0 is from Java 11

a very common question on this site. You should have taken the [tour]: "Don't ask about... * Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" and searched this site (or the internet)

I did look at other similar questions, but none explained my problem. After more digging, I now realize the problem was that Oracle maintains different version number sequences for the Consumer Version of Java (which is what I downloaded this morning), and the JDK. Turns out the Closure Compiler requires the JDK version, which I have never seen documented anywhere.

No, this isn't about JRE vs JDK, you just have Java 8 and you need 11. Or, you have both, but 8 is showing up on your path, so java -jar... is running 8 when you should be referring to 11.

All I know is I went to the official Oracle site to download the latest JRE, and it gave me Java 8. Sigh… Anyway, a moot point now, since I know to stick with the JDK.
